Encounter CORS issues with CRUD features when deploy to Render & Netlify
Currently, I'm trying to achieve the following features on my personal project

Feature #1: Displaying detailed information for each Pokemon on a new page
Feature #2: Updating the Pokemon on that page
Feature #3: Deleting the Pokemon on that page
Feature #4: Creating a new Pokemon with certain data

My website ran smoothly without any issues. However, after deploying backend code to Render and frontend code to Netlify, I encountered these errors for each feature with its own screenshot for more details

Feature #1: with 1 error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED. 
Feature #2: with 2 errors: CORS policy and Bad Gateway. However, the Pokemon's name was updated from Charizard to Charcoal.
Feature #3 & #4: with the same 2 errors in Feature #2. When I refresh the browser Pokemon Charcoal was deleted, but the next Pokemon, which is Squirtle, was not replaced Charcoal's location and rendered as expected when the website ran locally.

After some research, I added cors module to app.js in the backend code like the following code
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(
  cors({
   origin: "https://ultimate-pokedex-app.netlify.app",
   optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
);

The environment on Netlify, which is REACT_APP_BACKEND_API = https://pokedex-be-app.onrender.com, Render is empty. I tried to clear the browser's cache and ran the app again as well. However, the same errors remain.

My frontend code: https://github.com/PhucDong/pokedex-fe
My backend code: https://github.com/PhucDong/pokedex-be
Netlify: https://ultimate-pokedex-app.netlify.app

What should I do to fix the aforementioned errors?
